# How to check only columns in a dataframe whose column names meet a condition?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column in my dataframe that has a value of 1 if any of the conditions below hold, and 0 if none of them do. How can I do this in a more efficient way? Is there a way to use substr to check if any columns that start with "Q8" have a value greater than 0? I am using ifelse because I need it to be vectorized (it is going through 5000 rows, which are survey participants).

```
my.function <- function(my.data){
ifelse((my.data$Q8R1 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R2 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R3 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R4 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R5 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R6 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R7 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R8 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R9 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R10 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R11 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R12 > 0) |
       (my.data$Q8R13 > 0)
     , 1, 0)
}

my.data$new.variable <- my.function(my.data)
```

Some questions have over 50 records, and I do not want to have to write them all individually.

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of `rowSums(df[,grepl("^Q8", names(df)] > 0) > 0`?

Comment: A somewhat verbose possibility using `dplyr` and `tidyr` may work such as `my.data %>% gather(q8_type, q8_val, -Q1) %>% group_by(Q1) %>% summarise(new_var = ifelse(sum(q8_val>0), 1, 0))`